# java super class display method

Tags: java, methods, parent-child, super, display

I have a question, lets say I have class called `public class School{}` as a super class. and have `public class Student{}` & `public class instructor{}` as child class. and I have class called `public class SchoolDriver{}`

i have a method called

```
public void displayStudent(){
    super.display();
    System.out.println("I am student.");
}
```

on Student class.

I have a method called

```
public void displayInstructor(){
    super.display();
    System.out.println("I am instructor.");
}
```

on Instructor class.

I have a method called `public void display(){??????}`on School class

How to write displayInstructor() & displaystudent() on School  class display method?

Comment: what do you mean by "display my methods"?

Comment: the super class doesn't know these methods "exist". Create an abstract method and make the subclasses implement it. THen you can call it in the super class.

Comment: pass string parameter in display, pass it in the function as super.display("I am instructor.");

Answer (score 2):

> How to write displayInstructor() & displaystudent() on School class display method?

According to information provided it's not possible.

> I have class called `public class School{}` as a super class. and have `public class Student{}` & `public class instructor{}` as child class.

This object model makes no sense to me. Student is not a school and Instructor is not a school either. Inheritance represents an *is-a* relationship. So think about Student, Instructor and SchoolDriver as if they were people with different occupations. For example, you might have a Person class which would be a base class for all people.

```
public class Person {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getFullName();
    }
}
```

Then you might have classes which represent Student and Instructor accordingly. Note that I override `toString()` method instead of using `displayInstructor()` and `displaystudent()`.

```
public class Student extends Person {
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getFullName() + " is student";
    }
}

public class Instructor extends Student {
    public Instructor(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getFullName() + " is instructor";
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your code you can create people and call toString() method to display information about them.

```
Student student = new Student("John", "Smith");
Instructor instructor = new Instructor("John", "Rolfe");

System.out.println(student.toString());
System.out.println(instructor.toString());
```

Which will print the following

```
John Smith is student
John Rolfe is instructor
```